# Compilation error trying to communicate between Fragments with ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I followed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java) to implement communication between fragments. This is the relevant code from the guide:

```
    SharedViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    model.getSelected().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), { item ->
       // Update the UI.
    });
```

My actual code looks like this:

```
    HeaderViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(HeaderViewModel.class);
    TextView year = view.findViewById(R.id.year_text);
    model.getYear().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), { item -> year.setText(item) });
```

And this is the error I get:

```
error: illegal start of expression
    model.getYear().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), { item -> year.setText(item) });
                                                     ^
```

Why? What does this mean? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you stumbled across a typo in the documentation: the snippet you used is syntactically wrong, it should be

```
model.getYear().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), item -> {year.setText(item)});
```

Right above the buggy example there is another snippet with another lambda expression which shows how to do it correctly:

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel model;

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        model = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });
    }
}
```